# What's the proper way to wait for a .NET thread to start up?

Tags: c#, multithreading, doevents

I was reading the following on Microsoft's website within their threading tutorial:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

MSDN suggests using the following to wait for a thread to become alive:

```
while (!oThread.IsAlive);
```

Is this the recommended way to wait?  Would it be better to insert a "DoEvents" call to allow the main thread to remain responsive?  How should error handling be done in case something goes wrong and the thread never comes "alive?"  If this is bad practice, when is IsAlive best used?

A few moderators have marked this as a duplicate, but the other question they reference doesn't mention anything about IsAlive, DoEvents, or proper error handling if the thread fails to start.  My question is specifically related to the MSDN article I linked to within my question and its suggestion to use a busy loop with IsAlive.

Comment: Why do you need to wait for the thread to be alive?  What type of app is this?  WinForms, WPF, windows service, console, ...

Comment: I would think that the ideal solution would be for your main thread to continue with its business without caring when exactly the thread starts.  What are the specific requirements for your situation?

Comment: Agree with @mbeckish here; the entire point of a thread is that you don't care when, or if ever, it starts or finishes. If you want to get something back from a thread you should use `delegate.BeginInvoke()` or `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: If I used WaitOne() wouldn't the thread have to trigger a signal?  My question was more or less centered around why Microsoft would suggested using the IsAlive member.

Comment: In my situation, my thread is controlling something connected to a serial port.  The main thread would allow the user to send control commands to it via a UI, so really I don't want it to send anything until the thread is ready.  I just happened to be reading this on MSDN and wanted to know if using IsAlive in this case is good practice.

Comment: Some Microsoft "Tutorials" are... how shall I put this? A little *dated* nowadays. That one in particular has some things in that I really don't want to see in a tutorial. A main thread doing a busy wait via `while (!oThread.IsAlive);` instead of using something like a `ManualResetEvent`. And no reason given as to why you'd ever need to do such a thing anyway!

Comment: @DourHighArch I understand where you are coming from, but if that were always the case, why do thread synchronization facilities exist?

Comment: @MatthewWatson You make a very good point.  This is the kind of dialogue I am looking for regarding this situation.  My code seemed to be working fine as-is before I read this.  I just want to know other peoples' thoughts regarding the "busy wait" using IsAlive.

Comment: @gonzobrains Yes, "Don't do it" is my thoughts. :) How interested are you in proper threading? I'll dig out a link to a good free online book if you want.

Comment: Why can't the control commands queue up in the main thread, and the other thread can take as long as it needs to send them on to the serial port?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Speaking of being dated, what I am trying to look for is the most up-to-date tutorial which goes over the latest .NET threading facilities.  I'm familiar with 3.0 and when I started using 4.x I began getting deprecation warnings.  This is the main reason why I begun looking for a threading tutorial in the first place!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Awesome!  Please share the link!

Comment: @gonzobrains: This is the one: http://www.albahari.com/threading/ It even covers PLinq. I don't think it covers the new .Net 4.5 TPL tho.

Comment: I'm not sure why they marked this question as a duplicate as I believe it is distinct enough from the other question to justify being asked separately.  If it gets voted to be reopened you should post your comment as an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?  I think it has introduced some good discussion about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as there is no official answer yet... What you have seen on MSDN is from 2003, this is relatively old technology. For what you want to do I would use the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd460717.aspx). This requires .NET Framwork 4.0+.

For a great tutorial on how to use the TPL for what you require see:

1. [Task Parallel 1 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n).
2. [J. Albahari's Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Once you get to grips with TPL, feel free to come back and look for ask particular questions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you nailed it.  That MSDN article was just outdated and not very accurate.  This situation just goes to prove that "googling it" is not always sufficient.  Good thing we have dudes like you on SO to compensate!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Killercam's answer I want to point out that the sample code on the page linked is garbage. It looks like someone was told "create a sample that just shows all the different methods that we have on one page". And it literally came out like that...

When doing threading you almost never wait in a polling loop. Especially not in a tight one with any kind of waiting. They make the CPU hot, are unreliable, have high latency if you put a sleep in there and there are just better ways to do it. Spin loops are for experts who know what they're doing in very specific cases.

There is no point in waiting for a Thread to be "alive". Why would anyone do this in real code? This does not even mean that your thread proc has started executing (really! it doesn't.).

I recommend you use modern paradigms. The TPL is a good place to start. See Killercam's answer.

Comment: I see your point.  In defense of the article, perhaps some people would wait for it to be alive for synchronization purposes?  I'm just guessing.  There are probably better ways of implementing that though.

Comment: There's no point because alive means nothing. It doesn't mean your thread proc has started because the thread might just have been scheduled out at the first instruction. There's never a point in doing that by principle.